# samba 3.x.x vulnerabilities patch

Tags: centos, samba

We know that samba has few vulnerabilities. How to apply patches for  vulnerabilities of samba version 3 ?

samba site does not give clear info as to how to apply patches. Also is it possible to apply patches through a repo ?

Comment: What distribution are you using?

Comment: ` distribution is centos 5`

Answer (score 0):

In 99% of cases you're better off using your distribution's packages for standard software like Samba. All distributions will release updated Samba packages as soon as a security patch is released - update your Samba package to the latest and you will be fine.